# ConflictRefiner() returns a different upper bound than the one saved in the model

Tags: cplex, docplex

My model status is integer infeasible. I used `ConflictRefiner()` to check which constraints are mutually contradictory.

Then I use `display_conflicts` to check which constraints are "at fault".

This is the output:

[image]

I found this weird since my ub is set to 15. I checked the code and everything looks good and I also inspected the model values and as you can see for variable 107, `ub=15`.

[image: all_vars]

I can't really understand why this would happen. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How did you set the variable upper bound, at construction time, or later by setting the `ub` property?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this is a bug with DOcplex's conflict refiner; it does not take into account variable bounds set by properties. There are two workarounds:

- either define bounds what variable creation time.
- or start a solve() even with a small time limit(e.g. 1s) before launching the conflict refiner.

This bug will be fixed in the next release of DOcplex. Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: This bug is fixed in DOcplex 2.18, which was released today. Let me know if this fixes your problem.